# AWS GET api querying DynamoDB, using secondary index in the mapping template

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

DyanmoDB table details
table name: Product_Level
It has 3 Columns: PRODUCT(Partition key), COLOR(Sort key), Stock.

There's a requirement to access the data with only COLOR. In order to achieve that we are creating a secondary index on COLOR. I want to understand how do we make the change in the api.

-It has to work if I use either PRODUCT or COLOR

Currently, this is the code in Request Mapping Template:

```
"KeyConditionExpression": "PRODUCT = :a#if($input.params('color') != "") AND COLOR = :b#{end}",
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":a": {"S": "$input.params('product')"}#if($input.params('color') != ""),
    ":b": {"S": "$input.params('color')"}#{end}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify name of secondary index in the query.

Assume secondary index was created on "COLOR" and the index name is "COLOR-Index".

The query should be:

```
{
    TableName: "Product_Level",
    IndexName: "COLOR-Index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "COLOR = :COLOR",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":COLOR": COLOR
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. So, the PRODUCT in KeyConditionExpression isn't required? I should be able to query using PRODUCT also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query using PRODUCT and filter by COLOR, you don't need to create secondary index. This query should work:

```
{
    TableName: "Product_Level",
    KeyConditionExpression: "PRODUCT = :PRODUCT",
    FilterExpression: "contains (COLOR, :COLOR)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":PRODUCT": PRODUCT,
        ":COLOR" : COLOR
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know if you have the "product" and/or "color" (i.e. they are separate fields) you can store the data with a partition of the product, a sort of the color, and a GSI with a partition of the color. You'll need to run different queries based on what parameters you get.

With the data below you can run the following queries to get the data you want.

1. Get all of "ProductA" by just querying where "Partition = 'ProductA'"
2. Get all of the "Blue" records by querying with the GSI where "GSI_Partition = 'Blue'"
3. Get the "Red" "ProductA" record using a `GetItem` specifying the product and color keys.

```
Partition     Sort     GSI_Partition      Stock
ProductA      Red      Red                ...
ProductA      Blue     Blue               ...
ProductB      Blue     Blue               ...
```

If you really need to be able to specify *either* color *or* product in one query

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for answer on this, following is the correct mapping that worked for me:

```
{
    "TableName": "Product_Level",
    "IndexName": "COLOR-Index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "COLOR = :reque COLOR tId",
     "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
         ": COLOR": {
            "S": "$input.params('COLOR')"
    }
  }
}
```